# Limiting value of trigonometric expression

Tags: limits, derivatives, contest-math

Evaluate
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}{\left((2x+3)\left(\cos\frac{\pi x+3}{6x+1}-\sin\frac{2\pi x}{6x+1}\right)\right)}$$
I'm not able to convert this into a standard form like $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ and using L'Hôpital's rule seems to be very lengthy and requires more than 1 differentiation. Similarly, using taylor's expansion makes this question much too long. Is there a shorter way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $$L=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}{\left((2x+3)\left(\cos\frac{\pi x+3}{6x+1}-\sin\frac{2\pi x}{6x+1}\right)\right)}$$

First convert cosine to sine:
$$\cos\frac{\pi x+3}{6x+1}=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}2-\frac{\pi x+3}{6x+1}\right)$$

Next, use the property:

$$\sin A-\sin B=2\cos\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)$$

So we get:

$$\begin{align}\cos\left(\frac{\pi x+3}{6x+1}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{2\pi x}{6x+1}\right)&=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}2-\frac{\pi x+3}{6x+1}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{2\pi x}{6x+1}\right)\\
\\
&=2\cos\left(\frac{-6 + \pi + 8 \pi x}{4 + 24 x}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi-6}{4(1+6x)}\right)\end{align}$$

So the limit becomes:

$$\begin{align}
L&=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}{\left(2(2x+3)\cos\left(\frac{-6 + \pi + 8 \pi x}{4 + 24 x}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi-6}{4(1+6x)}\right)\right)}\\
\\
&=2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}{\left((2x+3)\sin\left(\frac{\pi-6}{4(1+6x)}\right)\right)}\end{align}$$

Can you proceed from here?